# Using VBA Macro to grid data sequentially in a new exel worksheet based on row headings

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am working with a data set that is set out by column header and as follows:
[image]

I am wanting to put together a VBA Macro to stack the data sequentially down the page in a new worksheet in the following column header order.

[image]

I'm looking for a macro that will loop thru worksheet A (raw data) and paste into an empty worksheet B as above.

Any ideas to execute this task would be really appreciated. I'll be working on this over coming days and will post what I come up with. Any improvements appreciated.

Comment: Does your data always jump two rows for the next data line?

Comment: Hi Ali, the data set comes out of a grants database and is quite lumpy in that there are sometimes two lines, and sometimes one line gaps. The data that I want to stack follows order in so much as the data to be stacked is always underneath the column header.

Answer (score 1):

your example doesn't provide a bullet-proof stacking rule

the following code follows a rule that matches the examples:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dataRng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim iDataA As Long, iDataE As Long

    With Worksheets("A")
        Set dataRng = .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    End With

    With Worksheets("B").Range("D4:J4")
        .value = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
        For Each cell In dataRng
            AddData cell, .Cells, iDataA, iDataE
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub

Sub AddData(cell As Range, outputRng As Range, iDataA As Long, iDataE As Long)
    With outputRng
        If cell = "A" Then
            iDataA = iDataA + 1
            If iDataA <= iDataE Then iDataA = iDataE + 1
            .Offset(iDataA).Resize(, 4).value = cell.Offset(1).Resize(, 4).value
        ElseIf cell = "E" Then
            iDataE = iDataE + 1
            .Offset(iDataE, 4).Resize(, 3).value = cell.Offset(1).Resize(, 3).value
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```